# pdo execute: ошибка запроса к БД

Tags: php, sql

Отправляю параметры для вставки в бд:

```
$c = ['login', 'password', 'email'];
$b = [$name, $password, $email];
$id = User::insertUser($c, $b);
```

Уходят в этот метод:

```
   public function insertUser($columns, $binds)
    {
        $insert = [];
        $data = [];
        foreach ($columns as $col) {
            if ($col == 'id' || $col == 'time') {
                continue;
            }
            $insert[] = ':' . $col;
            $data[':' . $col] = $binds[$col];
        }
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . static::$table . ' (' . implode(', ', $columns) . ')
                VALUES (' . implode(', ', $insert) . ')';
        $db = new Db();
        return $db->execute($sql, $data);
    }
```

Обрабатывает данный метод:

```
public function execute(string $sql, array $data = [])
    {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result = $sth->execute($data);
        if (false === $result) {
            throw new \Exception('Ошибка запроса к БД');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

На выходе FALSE и соответствующая ошибка запроса к БД. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему запрос неправильный?

Comment: Можете сделать `echo $sql` и показать что там нарисовано

Comment: добавьте выше `if (false === $result) {` этот код и получите ошибку `if (!$result) {
            var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
        }`

Comment: Дебаггинг? Какой дебаггинг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в строке

```
$data[':' . $col] = $binds[$col];
```

Вы передаете в $binds массив без ключей, значит там массив вида

`[0=>$name, 1=>$password, 2=>$email];`

а вы пытаетесь получить данные:

```
$binds['login'];
$binds['password'];
$binds['email'];
```

В итоге в $data у вас массив вида [':login'=>null, ':password'=>null, ':email'=>null], думаю дальше понятно.

Вам верно посоветовали узнать ошибку которую возвращает ваш запрос - '$sth->errorInfo()', та и посмотреть предварительно сам запрос который вы составили (хотя бы echo $sql).

Проще всего передать всего один массив, вместо двух:

```
$data=['login'=>login, 'password'=>$password, 'email'=>email];
$id = User::insertUser($data);

public function insertUser($data)
{
    //Стоит учесть что могут передать не массив
    if(!is_array($data)){
        throw new ErrorException('Need array');
    }

    //Удаляем из массива что не надо обрабатывать
    if(isset($data['id']) || isset($data['time'])){
        unset($data['id'], $data['time']);
    }

    //Получаем какие будем добавлять колонки
    $colums = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    //Создаем массив для метода execute
    $data = array_combine(
        array_map(function($v){ return ':'.$v; }, array_keys($data)),
        $data
    );
    $params = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    $tableName = static::$table;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ({$colums}) VALUES ({$params})";
    $db = new Db();
    return $db->execute($sql, $data);
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31f2e222c7bede42da0846689366074dad78a04b)

Можно прикрепить значения без названия, но нужно будет следить за порядком в массиве который передают, что бы прекрепить нужное к нужному:

```
$tableName = 'tableMane';
$c = ['login', 'password', 'email'];
$v = [111, 222, 333];

$colums = implode(',', $c);
$params = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($v), '?'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} ({$colums}) VALUES ({$params})";
//$db->execute($sql, $v);
echo $sql;
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c296ad3892ad1ccec7b9ee27f7ffdb1a996f0dd9)

Можно собрать значения в один массив и пойти первым путем:

```
$colums = ['login', 'password', 'email'];
$values = [$name, $password, $email];
$data = array_combine($colums, $values);
$id = User::insertUser($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас кода наворочено много и ошибку вы не написали. Могу привести пример рабочего запроса с биндингом параметра (переменной):

```
d = '2016-01-01';
$st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `groups` WHERE date=:date');
$st->bindParam(":date",  $d);
$st->execute();
```

Переменная $pdo это объект соединения с БД, он должен быть заранее создан уже.